# Euclidean Inequalities

Tags: geometry

How could I prove that the three Euclidean inequalities (given the three sides) are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a triangle? I have tried to solve it and look it up in many books but I did not find this proof.

Thank you,

Antonio Squadri

Comment: What did you try? :)

Comment: I would think that the Law of Cosines is enough. (Assuming one can take that as a starting point, at any rate.)

Comment: It is not enough. This is not a easy demonstration be sure this.

Comment: I would like to konw where I can find this demonstration. There is no space here to put it.

Answer (score 1):

Let your sides be $a$, $b$, and $c$.
Take a segment $AB$ of length $c$ and construct circles $O_A=C(A,b)$ and  $O_B=C(B,a)$ centered at its ends and or radii equal to the other sides.
These two circles intersect because there are points which are inside both and inside each one but not the other (you can construct such points on the line $AB$ using the triangle inequalities).

Comment: I want a formal demonstration. I know the informal demonstration.

Comment: This is as formal as it gets. Or maybe you want me to specify the specific axiom which I use at every step?